# Prop being mutated VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I get this error: "Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "filter" ",after I tried to move a section for fitering from parent to a child. The template is rendering, but when I type in the input I got that error.

**In Child**

```
<b-form-input
         v-model="filter"
         type="search"
         id="filterInput"
         placeholder="Type to Search"
    ></b-form-input>
<b-button :disabled="!filter" @click="filter = ''">Clear</b-button>

export default {
    name:'ExampleSearch',
    props:['filter'],

}
```

**In Parent**

```
   <ExampleSearch></ExampleSearch>

    <b-table
            ...code....
            :fields="fields"
            ...code....
    >

getExample(context) {
   ..code..
   if (typeof context !== 'undefined' && context.filter) {
         url += `&filter=${context.filter}`;
   }
   ..code..
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click event at `<b-button :disabled="!filter" @click="filter = ''">Clear</b-button>` is mutating `filter` prop at parent directly from child. That's why you are getting this error.

To avoid this you can modify `click` event listener as below where you `emit` the event to parent

```
...
<b-button :disabled="!filter" @click="$emit('clearFilter')">Clear</b-button>
...
```

And then at parent you can listen to this event via

```
...
<ExampleSearch :filter="filter" @clearFilter="filter=''" ></ExampleSearch>
...
```

If you are using vue  2.3.0 you can use `.sync` modifier which is shorthand for above expression.
Read more about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier)

Comment: Works for first "clear", second time I get the same error. But filtering still, doesn't work. I will read more from your link.

Answer (score 0):

Assign your props to a data to avoid that error.

```
data() {
 return {
  newFilter: this.filter
 }
}
```

Comment: I assign it in child, and I replace filter with newFilter in his template. But I get the same result.